# SQL NOT LIKE with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

*UPDATE*

I was able to find my solution by leveraging NOT EXISTS. Thus, my and statement looks like this:

```
and NOT EXISTS (select RejectCode from #rejects where od.UnitDescription LIKE ('%' + RejectCode + '%'))
```

This leverages a temp table #results in which I'm storing the 184 reject codes. THANK YOU everyone who responded. I went down each route, learned a few things, and the responses led me to the solution.

Post -> CTE -> Temp Table (couldn't assign a variable right after the CTE) -> Join on LIKE -> NOT EXISTS

*UPDATE*

I'm attempting to filter a query with a lot of conditions - the nested select statement below returns 184 reject codes. I have a unit description coming back that is a VARCHAR(100) and inside it contains a code (not in a static spot).

I'm attempting to do the following (summarized select for simplicity):

```
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104'
  and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE (select RejectCode
                                   from [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount 
                                   where GroupID = '15' 
                                     AND (DiscountPercent = '1' 
                                          or DiscountPercent = '.4' 
                                          or DiscountPercent = '.2'))
```

Previously I only had to filter on only a couple codes, so I simply did "and (od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE '%a%' and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE '%b%' and ...etc). My question would be: How do I use NOT LIKE, or something similar (since the UnitDescription is not static and contains more than just the reject code), to filter all of the codes returned from the nested select statement? Am I really doomed to write out "NOT LIKE" 184 times?

Comment: Could you consider building a temporary set of codes and inner joining that temporary set to orders.  In this way you are pre-establishing the list and writing your SQL based on an inclusive strategy rather than an exclusive strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it -- I can't see your exact example so you might need different columns in the criteria table.

```
with criteria as
(
   select 15 as groupid, '1' as discountpercent
union all
   select 15 as groupid, '.4' as discountpercent
union all
   select 15 as groupid, '.2' as discountpercent
), rejects
(
   select distinct RejectCode 
   from [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount rd
   join criteria c on c.groupid = rd.GroupID and c.discountpercent = rd.DiscountPercent
)
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104'
  and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE (select RejectCode from rejects)
```

As you can see I'm making the criteria information in a CTE but this could also be in a table (if you think it is going to expand often.)  You can also add more columns or more criteria sub-queries and then just union them in the rejects CTE as needed.

For example lets say you also have critera on foo and fab:

```
with criteria as
(
   select 15 as groupid, '1' as discountpercent
union all
   select 15 as groupid, '.4' as discountpercent
union all
   select 15 as groupid, '.2' as discountpercent
), critera2 as
(
   select 1 as foo, '1' as fab
union all
   select 2 as foo, '2' as fab
union all
   select 3 as foo, '3' as fab
), rejects as
(
   select distinct RejectCode 
   from [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount rd
   join criteria c on c.groupid = rd.GroupID and c.discountpercent = rd.DiscountPercent
   union
   select distinct RejectCode 
   from foofabrejectlist foofab
   join criteria2 c2 on c2.foo = foofab.foo and c2.fab = foofab.fab

)
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104'
  and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE (select RejectCode from rejects)
```

as you can see this can get quite "complex" quickly but still remain easy to maintain or make dynamic (by adding the criteria to a table.)

**Additional info as requested in the comments:**

To use join and not "NOT LIKE" do this:

```
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
left join rejects on od.UnitDescription = rejects.RejectCode
where CustomerID = '104'
  and rejects.RejectCode is null
```

NOTE: A good SQL optimizer should produce the same execution plan if you write it as a join or using the IN syntax.

Comment: @CodeBird - Well some problems take a while to solve.  If there is no business rule (eg discountpercent a multiple of Z) that can be used then a table (or virtual CTE one) is the best solution for a relational database.

Comment: could you also JOIN ON NOT LIKE to the rejects CTE?

Comment: hard to put in comment, but I was thinking your first query could be specified like `select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey join rejects r ON od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE r.RejectCode` or similar

Comment: or is that equivalent?

Comment: @chappoo - OH, you want to do a join, I'll show you how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response; I believe I'm on the right path to figuring this issue out. The join doesn't seem to work though. As stated the UnitDescription is much more than just the reject code. Thus od.UnitDescription = rejects.RejectCode will never match any rows and the RejectCode will always be null. I believe that additional query will simply return all units with no filter essentially. I tried changing the join to od.UnitDescription not like ('%' + rejects.RejectCode + '%') and this returns results, but duplicates each unit for every reject code in #rejects =/.

Answer (score 2):

Another way might be filtering the ids of those "like" it first and then selecting those "not in" the ids returned (this is assuming you have a column id in OrderDetails):

```
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104' and od.id not in (select od2.id 
                                           from OrderDetails od2 
                                           inner join [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount rd on od2.UnitDescription LIKE '%' + rejectCode + '%'
                                           where od2.CustomerID = '104' 
                                                 and rd.GroupID = '15' 
                                                 and (rd.DiscountPercent = '1' 
                                                 or rd.DiscountPercent = '.4' 
                                                 or rd.DiscountPercent = '.2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sub-query returns the results you want, and your only issue is how to use the "RejectCode" with the `%` wildcard for `LIKE`, you can simply solve that by using string concatenation. The idea is that ``` LIKE '%abc%`` is equivalent to ```LIKE '%' + 'abc' + '%'`, so you can use this concept to solve your issue. Something like this:

```
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104'
  and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE '%' + (select RejectCode
                                        from [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount 
                                        where GroupID = '15' 
                                        AND (DiscountPercent = '1' 
                                             or DiscountPercent = '.4' 
                                             or DiscountPercent = '.2')) + '%'
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with his question.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the reject code is a part of UnitDescription and not exactly the same as UnitDescription. So, prefixing and suffixing % with RejectCode in your query should work. Try this:

```
select od.*, o.*
from OrderDetails od
join Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
where CustomerID = '104'
and od.UnitDescription NOT LIKE (select '%' + RejectCode + '%'
                               from [CustDiscountTables].[dbo].RejectDiscount 
                               where GroupID = '15' 
                                 AND (DiscountPercent = '1' 
                                      or DiscountPercent = '.4' 
                                      or DiscountPercent = '.2'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This won't ever work, as his select return multiple rows